# How can i do tapply with filter on one of the variables

Tags: r, tapply

I'm using the `tapply` function in order to get the count of variable over another variable. Here is the line of code: `tapply(vip$VAR1,vip$VAR2,length)`

However, I would like to filter only observations that have the value "1" on `vip$VAR1`, can I do this with `tapply`?

```
dat <- read.table(text = " VAR1 VAR2 admit       num
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Where is "VAR1" and "VAR2" in your sample data?

Comment: fixed the dataframe, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do the trick?

```
tapply(dat[dat$VAR1==1,]$VAR1,dat[dat$VAR1==1,]$VAR2,length)
```

Or the simpler (from Ananda Mahto's comment):

```
with(dat[dat$VAR1 == 1, ], tapply(VAR1, VAR2, length))
```

Comment: I find the following a little easier to read: `with(dat[dat$VAR1 == 1, ], tapply(VAR1, VAR2, length))`.